# Volvo C70 camshaft position sensor

Tags: volvo, cam-position-sensor, c70

I have a Volvo C70 convertible with a 2.4L turbo. It was showing the code P0340 on the scanner. I bought the new camshaft position sensor; the housing broke while I was removing the old one. Bought housing with a sensor installed. I noticed no o-ring on the old sensor I took out. The new sensor had an o-ring, but the sensor that came in the housing I bought did not have an o-ring. So, I used the housing I bought and put the new sensor with the o-ring in it. Now it won't start. I noticed at online parts places that some have o-rings, and some don't. My question is, does my car have to have the 0-ring on that camshaft position sensor? If so, what could be the reason that it won't start now?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you have the part numbers (and where you bought them) for the stuff that you bought so we can cross reference and see if there are any issues? Also, what year is your C70?